# Connection error while sending the mail form local?

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm getting this error while sending the mail from the local in Magento.

```
2018-06-01 06:10:50 Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:587, timeout=300, options=array()
2018-06-01 06:10:51 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): SSL: The operation completed successfully. [C:\xampp\htdocs\Mailer\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php line 326]
2018-06-01 06:10:51 Connection: opened
2018-06-01 06:10:51 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2018-06-01 06:10:51 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
2018-06-01 06:10:51 Connection: closed
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

Comment: Have you install smtp extension?

Answer (score 0):

Download and Install magento smtp extension and follow steps,

```
https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmail-smtp-app
```

For magento1 install and follow,

```
   http://www.aschroder.com/product/smtppro-magento-smtp-email/
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes in local if you want to send mail then you have to configured SMTP third-party module here is the link which one is the best.

[Magepal SMTP Extension](https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmail-smtp-app/blob/master/registration.php)